# Targeting drop down box through ancestor/parent/etc..?

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, parent, ancestor

HTML code in question

```
<div class="wrap-padding-sm">
  <div class="threeCols">
    <div class="colContent">
      <div class="sub-colContent">
        <span>
          <div id="cust_opt_TypeCodeCheckBox_" class="  ">
            <div>
              <div class="uniform-checkbox    checked">.
                <div class="checker col-xs-1 col-md-1" id="uniform-bunny:h_abc257:0:cust_opt_TypeCodeCheckBox_:select-boolean-checkbox" style="display: block;">
                  <span class="checked">
                    <input id="bunny:h_abc257:0:cust_opt_TypeCodeCheckBox_:select-boolean-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="bunny:h_abc257:0:cust_opt_TypeCodeCheckBox_:select-boolean-checkbox" checked="checked" class=" " onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','bunny:custom_bunny_hops','bunny:custom_bunny_hops',{'onevent':recommendedBunnyAfterAJAX})">
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
        <span class="checkTitle">This money</span>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-colContent">
        <div class="select-dropWrap">
          <div id="h_abc281" class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <label for="bunny:h_abc257:0:h_abc281:select-one-menu" class="control-label">up to </label>
            <div class="select-dropMenu  ">
              <div class="selector uniform-select fixedWidth" id="uniform-changeCoverages:j_idt257:0:j_idt281:select-one-menu">
                <span style="user-select: none;">600</span>
                <select id="bunny:h_abc257:0:h_abc281:select-one-menu" name="bunny:h_abc257:0:h_abc281:select-one-menu" class="form-control input-lg  " size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','bunny:custom_bunny_hops','bunny:custom_bunny_hops',{'onevent':recommendedBunnyAfterAJAX})">
                  <option value="600" selected="selected">600</option>
                  <option value="800">800</option>
                  <option value="1000">1000</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="bunnyMsg h7 mobile-show"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="colContent">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" class="margin-R10" data-target="#cust_bunny_hops_0">
        <span>some text here</span>
      </a>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cust_bunny_hops_0" class="btn-accordian collapsed"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="cust_bunny_hops_0" class="bunny-wrap collapse">
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>
  <span class="bunnyMsg h7 mobile-hide"></span>
</div>
```

What I need to do is target

```
<span class="checkTitle">This money </span>
```

and from there target the drop down menu. 
I managed to target it using

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'This money')]//ancestor::span[1]//select")));
```

and it works when `dropDown.selectByValue("800");`. The problem now occurs if I try to select another dropdown menu I get **StaleElementReferenceException**.

**I solved the StaleElementReferenceException** by changing my code from this

```
 Select dropDownTwo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*  [contains(text(), 'This money')]/following::select")));
 Select dropDownTwo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*  [contains(text(), 'Another drop down not in the HTML above')]/following::select")));
 dropDown.selectByValue("800");
 dropDownTwo.selectByValue("1000000");
```

to this

```
 Select dropDownTwo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*  [contains(text(), 'This money')]/following::select")));
 dropDown.selectByValue("800");
 Select dropDownTwo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*  [contains(text(), 'Another drop down not in the HTML above')]/following::select")));
 dropDown.selectByValue("1000000");
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea. Now I just need to wait 90 minutes to post my second question.

Comment: I don't see `By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Income Replacement')]")` anywhere in the HTML. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry. Just fixed it above. Old value snuck in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the HTML provided, the `SELECT` you seem to be looking for is the first `SELECT` after the reference tag you specified,

```
<span class="checkTitle">This money</span>
```

Because of this, you can use the XPath below.

```
//span[contains(.,'This money')]/following::select
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, thank you. Only other thing now is StaleElementReferenceException when I try to select another drop down on the page.

Comment: That would be a separate question. Post a new question including all the code attempts, relevant HTML, etc. and I'll probably see it or someone else can help you.

Comment: I solved it anyways. Just had target it after finishing with the previous drop down. Thanks again.